# Is it safe to store id into real class pointer before checking type

Tags: objective-c

I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
id myObjectRaw = getObject();
if(![myObjectRaw isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) return nil;
MyClass * myObject = myObjectRaw;
...
```

Here `id getObject()` can return several kinds of object. However the above code feels clunky to me. Is it safe to write this?

```
MyClass * myObject = getObject();
if(![myObject isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]) return nil;
...
```

The compiler doesn't complain, but I'm not sure that I'm not treading on undefined behaviuor if `getObject` returns an object not related to `MyClass`.

(And no, I can't use a super class, or interface, since I dont actually have control over all the classes that get returned.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions will work. The first feels clunky, but there are problems with the second one as well: Putting something into a variable of a specific type implies knowledge of its type, and checking the class of something that seems to be known already looks redundant. If someone (it might be you) looks at that code next year, he may find the class check superfluous and remove it.

I've been in a similar situation, and I went with a helper method that gives a properly typed result or nil, i.e.

```
-(Rectangle)getRectangleObject {
   id data = getObject();
   if ([data isKindOfClass:[Rectangle class]]) return data;
   return nil;
}
```

This simplifies code and communicates the intention clearly.
If you need several different type checks, you can go with several methods, or pass the class to this helper method.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it. Nothing undefined. The only danger is that if the type is wrong and you forget to check the type, it may crash due to unrecognized selector exception.

In compiled code, `id`, `MyClass *` and `NSString *` have no difference, they just a pointer to a ObjC object.

Answer (score 2):

As long as all types of returned objects conform to `NSObject` protocol (Classes that inherit from `NSObject` class do) it is safe to use `isKindOfClass:` method.

So make sure `getObject()` method only returns objective-c classes that inherit from `NSObject`

**EDIT**

While compiler is fine with it, as @Eiko mentions someone reading the code will probably think the `isKindOfClass:` check is unnecessary. It is better to use the former code to let the reader know that `getObject()` might also return other types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `id myObjectRaw` you are NOT defining what kind of object `myObjectRaw` is, thus the compiler won't know if `MyClass * myObject = getObject();` is a valid operation or not. THe compiler assumes you know what you are doing. If `getObject()` returns an object that is different than `MyClass` or it's not a subclass of it your app may crash. This is a runtime error.

If `getObject()` returns different objects, you should be expecting at least one object of the kind of objects that can be returned. If need to handle different objects, you can always use if-else-if instructions like:

```
id myObjectRaw = getObject();

if([myObjectRaw isKindOfClass:[MyClass1 class]])
{
    MyClass1 objectClass1 = myObjectRaw;
}
else if([myObjectRaw isKindOfClass[MyClass2 class]])
{
    MyClass2 objectClass2 = myObjectRaw;
}
```

However, if the object returned is a `MyClass2` object, and this class is a subclass of `MyClass1` the first condition will be true. Therefore, the object will be saved as a `MyClass1` object. If that's the case you need to establish priorities and put them accordingly in the nested if-else-if statement.

Comment: *"The condition is always going to be true ..."* - This is wrong. It does not matter at all how the object is *declared*, `isKindOfClass` checks the class at runtime.

Comment: If the App crashes with the wrong type, it will crash with the right type as well.

Comment: Eiko-> Not necessarily. Let's say the method returns both `NSArray` and `NSString` objects but you do this: `NSString *string = [self method];` because you declared `string` as an `NSString` object you can make use of `string.lastPathComponent`. If the object returned by `[self method]` is `NSString` everything will work well, but if the object returned is a `NSArray` then an exception will be thrown. Reason? `unrecognized selector sent to instance`